# TimeZoneInfo - same TimeZoneInfo id, different Daylight Savings support value

Tags: .net, datetime

We have a server which is failing to handle daylight saving time correctly wrt C# DateTime instances converting from UTC to local time. We are in the UK so have our servers set to "(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London" region.

Symptom:

```
DateTime utcTime = new DateTime(2020, 10, 15, 23, 53, 20, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime localTime = utcTime.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine($"UTC time: {utcTime:s}");
Console.WriteLine($"Local time: {localTime:s}");

UTC time: 2020-10-15T23:53:20
Local time: 2020-10-15T23:53:20 // should be 2020-10-16T00:53:20
```

Investigation:

```
var gmt = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
Console.WriteLine("GMT:");
Console.WriteLine($"ID: {gmt.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"DisplayName: {gmt.DisplayName}");
Console.WriteLine($"DST: {gmt.SupportsDaylightSavingTime}");
var local = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
Console.WriteLine("Local:");
Console.WriteLine($"ID: {local.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"DisplayName: {local.DisplayName}");
Console.WriteLine($"DST: {local.SupportsDaylightSavingTime}");
```

On "normal" workstations and servers, the output is:

```
GMT:
ID: GMT Standard Time
DisplayName: (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
DST: True

Local:
ID: GMT Standard Time
DisplayName: (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
DST: True
```

On the rogue server, it is:

```
GMT:
ID: GMT Standard Time
DisplayName: (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
DST: True

Local:
ID: GMT Standard Time
DisplayName: GMT Standard Time
DST: False
```

What could be the origin of this "GMT Standard Time" time zone info instance that has the same ID but a different name and DST support?

"rogue" server is Windows Server 2012 R2. I don't see anything obviously out of place in the registry keys

e.g. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\ has a "GMT Standard Time" key under it which declares the name "(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ the TimeZoneKeyName value is "GMT Standard Time"

EDIT:
We're running .NET framework code.
The UTC-to-local conversion failure shows up in both .NET v2 and .NET v4.7.2.

Comment: check out the `TZI` values from the `GMT Standard Time` key - are they the same between severs? I suspect the [DaylightBias](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs,317) is somehow different

Comment: You most probably don't use mono on a Windows Server, right? there was once a similar-ish [issue](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/8267).

Comment: Thanks, but no. Regular Windows desktop apps compiled from C# by Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: You could use ProcMon tool from sysinternals and run your same little code (filter by process name) on your server vs a normal machine. There should be some registry or file difference (full range of touched keys is wide).

Comment: You should take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/482860/does-windows-8-support-utc-as-bios-time/497666#497666 to let Windows leave BIOS clock as UTC

Comment: On the rogue server, please try changing to any other time zone, then change back and try again.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint - It's on the list of actions we can do, but we'd like to get to the underlying cause if possible first before tinkering with a production server which is seemingly ok for its other tasks.

Comment: Ok.  Please expect the entire key and all values of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation` and add them to the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is right there in your outputs. You say the rouge server isn't supporting DST correctly and then when you inspect the time zone you see:

> DST: False

Where the other servers show True.

You have two options, either:

1. Check the DST settings in code and add offset when it's not as expected
2. Enable DST on all servers to be the same

I would go with #2 because this is going to come up for all applications, not just yours. The server will be off by an hour for part of the year. So sometimes it's not a problem and then other times it is. Normally, you just hit the checkmark for enabling Daylight savings time in the clock settings. You cite registry values so here is the one for DST:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation

Value Name: DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0
```

Setting `DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled = 0` should make it so `DST = True` on this machine and it should then behave like the other ones.